# How to update large dataset with MySQL migration scripts

Tags: javascript, mysql, json

We are developping a Nodejs app for a client that demanded that we use migration scripts to facilitate update the production database. Since i'm new to MySQL , i can't wrap my head around something, which is, how am i supposed to update tables content with only MySQL when i need to do some API calls to get the updated information, compare it to the current one and then update what needs to be updated.

What i did so far is, saving the new data in a JSON file. Is it possible to read a JSON with MySQL and import its content. This is what i want to do :

```
// read json file and star a loop
UPDATE table SET column = data WHERE id = json_id
// data and json_id are information from the JSON file
```

Is that possible ? if so how can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a migration script. You can create a .sql file with scripts for create, update, and whatever you need for tables, stores procedures etc. Now when you want to deploy your app in production environment you can execute this script in the production instace and this will recreate your tables, sp's and even data if you want. You don't need an api endpoint for that.

Comment: but how can read a JSON file from mySQL to get the new data from ?

Comment: You can do that you don't need to do so. you can create a single file with the creations of tables: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-create-table/ and later the insert of the data: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp, execute the .sql file and the database will be created and populated with a single file